# how do you parse a line array in php

Tags: php

I have line array that has content like this:

```
 5   1   0   49972729    1813694     7   218     0     0     0      0   747  16811 13911  1  1 96  1  0.53   3.3 12:51:44
 6   1   0   49976522    1806247     3   203     0     0     0      0   613  41885 13113  3  2 95  1  0.86   5.4 12:52:14
  kthr            memory                         page                       faults                 cpu             time
---------- --------------------- ------------------------------------ ------------------ ----------------------- --------
 r   b   p        avm        fre    fi    fo    pi    po    fr     sr    in     sy    cs us sy id wa    pc    ec hr mi se
 8   1   0   49979036    1800213     1   190     0     0     0      0   650  54141 14509  2  2 95  1  0.80   5.0 12:52:44
 6   1   0   49981360    1807204     2   235     0     0     0      0   641  31630 18005  2  1 96  1  0.70   4.4 12:53:14
```

I would like to go though each line and every line that starts with a number push that to a ne array.

I have this so far:

```
{for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($line); $i++)
if(preg_match("^[0-9]", $line[i]) 
  array_push($line[$i], $new_line);

}
```

I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\PHP\cpu.php on line 20
```

I am very new to php and really appreciate any insight.

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: You are missing a `)` at the end of your `if` for start.

Comment: Is OP also aware of PHP's [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rawLines = explode("\n", $content);
$lines = array();
foreach($rawLines as $rawLine){
    $rawLine = trim($rawLine);
    $parts = explode(" ", $rawLine); //maybe explode("\t", $rawLine);
    $parts[0] = trim($parts[0]);
    if( !ctype_digit($parts[0]) ){
        continue;
    }
    $lines[] = $parts;
}
```

Comment: the last line $lines[], contain all of my lines? how would I print it? I tried echo $lines[0], it gave me the output as "array"

Comment: what I am ultimately need to do is to insert the last $lines array to db table.

Comment: $lines contains an array of your lines, each entry in the array is an array of the numbers in your lines.. to print it as a string do: foreach($lines as $line){ echo implode(" ", $line), "<br>"; } after the foreach in the code..

Answer (score 0):

When you fix the syntax errors for your script (missing `)` for example), you will need delimiters for your regex:

```
if(preg_match("/^[0-9]/", $line[$i]))
               ^ here ^
```